# Ripples stucked in old Android wallet

Tags: wallet, ripple, wallet-recovery

Recently I found some ripples in an Android wallet called RippleWallet. This application doesn't exist on the Play Store anymore and I don't remember where I downloaded it (dumb I know but it was 2 years ago and I didn't cared much). 
When I try to send these ripples, the application is unresponsive and doesn't do anything. 
So do you know if these coins are lost forever? Or maybe I can get access to them by finding the secret key using adb or any other kind of file explorer? I don't even know what to look for..

Thanks in advance,

PS : This is my first time posting here, let me know if I infringed any rules.